# Code Refactoring, How to Avoid double for loops

Tags: java, java-8, refactoring

I am using two loops to create an image object which contains the path to the image in the file system
I could not avoid using two for loops to do this task.
Can I do the same thing using one for loop?

```
   List<String> filesInFolder = null;
       List<Image> images = new ArrayList<Image>();
       try {
           filesInFolder = Files.walk(Paths.get(path)).filter(Files::isRegularFile).map(Path::toString)
                   .collect(Collectors.toList());
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       for (int i = 0; i < filesInFolder.size(); i++) {
           images.add(new Image(filesInFolder.get(i)));
       }
```

Comment: `images = Files.walk(Paths.get(path)).filter(Files::isRegularFile).map(p->new Image(p.toString())).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: ya, as easy as that, thanks